# Poisson equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

> Consider, on a rectangle ($0<x<L,\ 0<y<H$)
>   $$\begin{cases} \triangledown^2u=Q(x,y), \text{on $D$}\\
> \triangledown u \cdot\vec{n}=0\ \text{on $\partial D$} \end{cases}$$
>   Solve using the method of eigenfunction expansion.

So we wish to use the method of eigenfunction expansion. I am however stuck using the boundary conditions for this problem. So the idea is that we use the method of seperation of variables, which results in:

$$\begin{cases}
\triangledown^2\phi=-\lambda\phi\ o\text{n}\ D\\
\phi\cdot\vec{n}=0\ \text{on}\ \partial D
\end{cases}
\\ u(x,y)=\sum_ia_i\phi_i$$

Could anyone give me a hint on how to continue this problem? I presume I need the Divergence theorem, which states (for this problem):

$$-\lambda\iint_D\phi dV=\iint_D \triangledown^2\phi dV\\=\oint_{\partial D}\triangledown\phi\cdot\vec{n}dV=0$$
But I am not sure how to continue with this result.

Comment: You're probably familiar with the eigenfunctions on an interval. One can prove that the eigenfunctions on a product $D_1 \times D_2$ are products of eigenfunctions on $D_1$ and $D_2$. In your case this gives you products of appropriate sine functions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2 cosine functions?

Comment: I understand that you prefer cosine to sine because of the Neumann boundary conditions? You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with $\nabla^2\phi = \lambda \phi$. Use separation of variables in $xy$-plane. Then you get the set of eigenfunctions. Write most general form of expansion and impose boundary conditions. Then construct Green function in terms of eigenfunctions. With the Green function, and $Q(x,y)$ as source, find solution $u(x,y)$.